# Satisfying of $\square (\neg A \cup B)$

Tags: logic, linear-temporal-logic

Let's consider the following formula:
$\square (\neg A \cup B)$.

Does the following computation satisfy it?

The numbers in brackets are number of state.

(0) $\neg A, \neg B$

(1) $\neg A, B$

(2) $A, \neg B$

$\square$ means that for **every** state in computation the formula $\neg A \cup B$ is satisfied, so: In $0$ state it is satisfied. In $1$ it is satfisfied. But, in $2$ state it is unsatisfied because $\cup$ says that $A$ must be false until $B$ is true.

So, the formula is not satisfied.

But, it seems that my reasoning is incorrect because I test it for simple program in Promela and my tests suggest that the formula is satisified, though, my reasoning is incorrect.

Please help me .

```
inline test_and_set(addr, old) {
  d_step{
    old = addr;
    addr = 1;
  }
}
byte lock;
active [2] proctype proc(){
  byte old;
  do
  :: true ->
    wait:
      test_and_set(lock, old);
      do
      :: old != 0 -> test_and_set(lock, old);
      :: else -> break;
      od
    cs:
    lock = 0;
  od
}

ltl prop {((!proc[0]@cs) W proc[0]@wait) // (***)
```

And I verified it with 
`spin -a test.pml  ; gcc -O2 pan.c -o pan ; ./pan -a -f`

And it has 0 errors. When I replace (***) with `ltl prop{([](!proc[0]@cs) W proc[0]@wait))}`
I've got an error.

Why?

Comment: It may simply be a precedence problem: $\neg A U B$ gets parsed as $\neg (A U B)$. Try $(\neg A) U B$ instead.

Comment: So, do you mean that `spin` should find a counterexample for my formula? So, what is correct interpretation of that?

Comment: I would need to see the actual Promela program you used.

Comment: I've edited.  :)

Comment: Note that you are using the weak until operator W instead of the strong until U. `p W q` does not require `q` being eventually true.

Comment: I know it. When I change it with `U` (strong until) I am still confused,

Comment: @chi, but why the formula with $\square$ at beginning gives an error while the one without doesn't.